# Android Auto noise during phone call

Tags: calls, bluetooth-audio, android-auto

After the last update, my Android phone stopped interfacing correctly with the Android Auto infotainment system during phone calls.

To be more specific, it is impossible to make or receive a phone call over Bluetooth because the phone source just sends unbearable noise to the car's loudspeakers. All other multimedia and controls work just fine, but the only way to manage a phone call is to tap on the car screen and select the phone loudspeaker as output.

Any clues on how to reset audio settings without doing a factory reset? Other ideas?

Comment: Its possible that it an app that you have installed recently.

Comment: I had installed windows link to phone recently, I tried uninstalling, just in case. No difference